# How to take a photo by Volume Key in Android Phone

Tags: android, camera

When I drove my bike, I like to take photos using my phone (Samsung i9103 android 2.3.6).
I want to sit with my Phone on the bike and take photos by pressing the Volume button on  my earphone.

So what should i do?

I'm a webdevloper but i can write an easy app, or is there any app that already can do this? starting the camera by volume button.

Comment: belongs to http://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [application1](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/media_and_video/volume-key-camera_pffj.html) or [application2](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/photography/volshutter-camera-free_bevax.html?nav=related)

Comment: It's cant use button on earphone

Comment: I suggest you state the problem you are facing clearly

Comment: He did in the original question

Answer (score 0):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mgrmobi.photobutton
Works great on my S4

You should check about you mobile. Possibly it will work.